# window.location.replace(); no funciona

Tags: javascript, macos

Estoy haciendo un pa pagina web con diferentes documentos html. Desde windows me funciona, pero con OS X no.

Este es el método en el que lo tengo escrito:

```
function guardarCookies() {

    if ($("#Conditions").prop("checked") == false) {

        alert("You must accept the terms of service and conditions.");
    } 
    else if ($("#Password").val().localeCompare($("#Password_confirmation").val())) {

        alert("The password and the confirmation of the password aren't the same.");

    } 
    else if ($("#Gender option:selected").val().localeCompare("0") == 0) {

        alert("You must choose a gender.");

    } 

    else {

        document.cookie = name + ":Name=" + document.getElementById("Name").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":LastName=" + document.getElementById("LastName").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Email=" + document.getElementById("Email").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Password=" + document.getElementById("Password").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Password_confirmation=" + document.getElementById("Password_confirmation").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":dia=" + document.getElementById("dia").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":mes=" + document.getElementById("mes").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":ano=" + document.getElementById("ano").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Gender=" + $("#Gender option:selected").val() + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Ncard=" + document.getElementById("Ncard").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":mesCD=" + document.getElementById("mesCD").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":anoCD=" + document.getElementById("anoCD").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":codigo=" + document.getElementById("codigo").value + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Publicidad=" + $("#Publicidad").prop("checked") + ";";
        document.cookie = name + ":Imagen=" + document.getElementById("Imagen_subida").src + ";";    

    window.location.href = '../MainPage.html'
    }


}
```

---

Codigo dentro del form

```
            <div id="Name_sname" class="Inputs col-md-12">

                <input class="input" type="text" id="Name" placeholder="First" required>
                <input class="input" type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last" required>


                <input id="bimg" onclick="clickButton()" type="image" src="Images/bimg.png" width="40" height="40">
                <input id="fotocargada" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadPicture()" class="formulario">
                <img id="Imagen_subida" src="" style="width:40px;height:40px;">

            </div>
```

Comment: Para redireccionar a otra página debes incluir la parte `window.location.href = 'http://tudomioOlocalhost.com/MainPage.html'`

Comment: No no tiene porque. Si la ruta de la nueva página es la misma que la actual no debería hacer falta indicar la url completa.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar `window.location.href="<url>";`

De esta forma te funcionará en todos los navegadores.

Si la nueva página está en la misma ruta que la actual debería bastarte con indicar la página a cargar:

```
window.location.href = 'MainPage.html';
```

Si no te funciona en algún navegador puedes probar introduciendo la url completa (pero no debería hacer falta):

```
var path = window.location.origin + (window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
window.location.href = path + 'MainPage.html';
```

Comment: Lo he intentado así también y me da el mismo resultado. Estoy intentando redireccionar a otra pagina html de la misma carpeta.

Comment: Con `window.location.replace` no te va a funcionar en muchos navegadores. Con `window.location.href` debería funcionarte en todos. ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: No debería hacer falta, pero puedes probar a poner la url completa. He editado la respuesta para mostrarte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Ya he visto el problema, a ver si sabes que puedo hacer. Resulta que si pongo esto " window.location.href = '../MainPage.html' " y me funciona si en el form que tengo no subo una imagen. He actualizado la pregunta con el resto el div que contiene la imagen.